# Absolute Positioning of H1 Results in Extra Padding Around Element

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div around an h1 element that I am trying to place absolutely on the screen.
However, when I change the div's position to absolute, there is an extra space above and below the h1 element that I cannot get rid of.

```
 .parent {
   width: fit-content;
   height: fit-content;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
 }


 h1 {
  // no styling
 }
```

In this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCUKv.png)

It shows the spacing problem.

The green outline is the parent div with an absolute position and the blue is the h1 inside. There is always extra spacing around the h1 when position is absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove/reset or adjust margin and padding of the parent div.
Like sample code below.

```css
.main {
  background-color: red;
  width: 55px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 24px;
  position: relative;
 }
 
 .parent {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
 }

 h1 {
  background-color: green;
 }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```